# python: force non-relative import?

Tags: python, module, path, import, importerror

I wanted to make a module called `utils/django.py` in my project. On the top I have the line:

```
from django.db import models
```

However, it tries to import from itself, and that causes an error. I know I can force a relative import with a prepended `.`:

```
from .django.db import models
```

is there any way to force a non-relative import?

Comment: You could also just rename the file. Relative imports are *highly discouraged*, you should for example `import myapp.stuff.django` instead.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to import a class from within the file that it's defined. If that's the case, then you can refer to the class db.models directly without importing it.

Comment: @JochenRitzel And how would you propose to do that? Append a number to the module's name? An underscore? Sometimes the same name is the only name that makes sense, and what you're proposing does not even try to be a solution to the problem...

Comment: It's worth making a note that it's not the relative imports themselves that are discouraged, it's the _implicit_ ones (lacking a leading `.`) that are bad for humanity.  Python 3 disallows implicit relative imports for this reason.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. You need to explicitly enable [absolute imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Comment: This is the way you're supposed to do it in Python2. In Python3 absolute imports are default.